# sqlsrv_query resource is unknown when returned

Tags: php

I'm having an issue with `sqlsrv_query();`

I dont think this is a duplicate as i have been searching through other questions, but if it is i do apologise.

I have two php files one with the databse functions and one using them, the database file is included in the top of the file using it.

In the databse file i have two functions (Along with other connection functions);

```
function database_GetData($sql) {
    $connection = database_GetDatabaseConnection();
    return sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql);
}

function database_ReadData($rs) {
    if (!$rs)
        return false;
    $data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rs);
    return $data;
}
```

The issue is that the `database_GetData($sql)` returns the resource but it is "unknown". If i print the `sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql)` result in the function or do something along the lines of `sqlsrv_fetch_array(sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql))` within the function i get the expected result but as soon as i return the resource it gets messed up. The connection is all fine as i get the expected result but cannot return it. I would like to keep the functions the same as they are used throughout the application.

Is there any reason why a result of `sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql)` would get set to 'unknown' once returned from `database_GetData($sql)` function?

Comment: What is the result of var_dump(sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql)); ?

Answer (score 0):

by ref parameters

```
function database_GetData($sql,&$resutl) {
     $connection = database_GetDatabaseConnection();
     $result=sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql);
     return $result;
}
```